# Starting Batch process from a stream job

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Hi I have a maven project for Flink stream processing. Based the message I get from the stream I start a batch process but currently I am getting an error.

I am pretty new to this flink world and please let me know if you have any idea. Here is the code I am using to start a standalone cluster.

```
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment ( );

    KafkaConsumerService kafkaConsumerService= new KafkaConsumerService();
    FlinkKafkaConsumer010<String> kafkaConsumer = kafkaConsumerService.getKafkaConsumer(settings );
    DataStream<String> messageStream = env.addSource (kafkaConsumer).setParallelism (3);

    messageStream
            .filter(new MyFilter()).setParallelism(3).name("Filter")
            .map(new ProcessFile(arg)).setParallelism(3).name("start batch")
            .addSink(new DiscardingSink()).setParallelism(3).name("DiscardData");

    env.execute("Stream processor");
```

//ProcessFile map class

```
    public ProcessFile(String arg) { }

@Override
public String map(String message) throws Exception {
    MessageType typedmessage = ParseMessage(message);
    if (isWhatIwant()) {
        String[] batchArgs = createBatchArgs();
                    Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.setString(JobManagerOptions.ADDRESS, jobMasterHost);
        config.setInteger(JobManagerOptions.PORT, jobMasterPort);

        StandaloneClusterClient client = new StandaloneClusterClient(config);
        client.setDetached(true);
        PackagedProgram program = new PackagedProgram(new File(jarLocation), SupplyBatchJob.class.getName(), batchArgs);
        client.run(program, 7);
    }

    return typedmessage;
}
```

The error is copied from the Job manager web portal. Error I am getting:     org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Failed to retrieve the JobManager gateway.
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.runDetached(ClusterClient.java:497)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.StandaloneClusterClient.submitJob(StandaloneClusterClient.java:103)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:442)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.DetachedEnvironment.finalizeExecute(DetachedEnvironment.java:76)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:387)
    at cw.supply.data.parser.maps.ProcessFileMessage.map(ProcessFileMessage.java:47)
    at cw.supply.data.parser.maps.ProcessFileMessage.map(ProcessFileMessage.java:25)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamMap.processElement(StreamMap.java:41)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:528)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:503)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:483)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:891)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:869)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamFilter.processElement(StreamFilter.java:40)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:528)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:503)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:483)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:891)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:869)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$NonTimestampContext.collect(StreamSourceContexts.java:103)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$NonTimestampContext.collectWithTimestamp(StreamSourceContexts.java:110)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.AbstractFetcher.emitRecordWithTimestamp(AbstractFetcher.java:269)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.Kafka010Fetcher.emitRecord(Kafka010Fetcher.java:86)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.Kafka09Fetcher.runFetchLoop(Kafka09Fetcher.java:152)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.run(FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java:483)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:87)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:55)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask.run(SourceStreamTask.java:95)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:263)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:702)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Could not connect to the leading JobManager. Please check that the JobManager is running.
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.getJobManagerGateway(ClusterClient.java:789)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.runDetached(ClusterClient.java:495)
    ... 30 more
     Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.leaderretrieval.LeaderRetrievalException: Could not retrieve the leader gateway.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.util.LeaderRetrievalUtils.retrieveLeaderGateway(LeaderRetrievalUtils.java:79)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.getJobManagerGateway(ClusterClient.java:784)
    ... 31 more
      Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:190)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:190)
    at scala.concurrent.Await.result(package.scala)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.util.LeaderRetrievalUtils.retrieveLeaderGateway(LeaderRetrievalUtils.java:77)
    ... 32 more

Answer (score 1):

I figured what the issue is after getting access to the environment I verified. I was using the public address of the JobManager where the port is not open. Instead I started using the private IP since all nodes are in the same subnet and no need of opening the port to the world. Hope this helps someone else too.